# How to represent number formats internally?

Tags: database, internationalization, number-formatting

Recently I started to work on some internationalization aspects of my project, and I need to build a user preference to display numbers (arabic numbers) in their accustomed format.

I did some research online and despite a surprisingly lack of reliant standard documentation I found [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/78175/International-Number-Formats) which outlines 7 formats out there. Which is a good starting point.

The question is, how do I represent/store those formats internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting numbers should be done at the view level only, so simply store them as regular integers (or floats, depending on your need).

Then only when you need to display them, format them per the current locale.

To store them in the database, since the format is defined by the decimal separator (either "," or ".") and the thousand separator (" ", "," or nothing), I'd just use two simple varchar columns, eg. format_dec_seprator and format_thousand_separator to represent the format.

If some formats don't separate thousands, you can use an empty string separator.

Comment: Yes of course the formatting is done at the render time. I am talking about storing the "format" which the number should be formatted. Like for example 1000 can be formatted as "1,000.00" or "1.000,00" and this is user configurable, not just based on locale. So I will need a representation of the format and store it along with the user's preference.

Comment: @Xavier_Ex, ah I see what you mean. Since the format is defined by the decimal separator (either "," or ".") and the thousand separator (" ", "," or nothing), I'd just use two simple varchar columns, eg. format_dec_seprator and format_thousand_separator to represent the format.

Comment: That is an interesting perspective. But we also need to keep in mind that not all formats separate numbers in thousands, so I can't just assume that either...

Comment: In that case, the thousand separator would simply be an empty string.

Comment: @Xavier_Ex I'd simply number all known possibilities (and add more upon request if even one happens). Two columns sound good (normal form and whatever), but IMHO it's an overkill (a `VARCHAR(2)` for both separators should do). The important thing is: /Write a class taking care of it, so that the interpretation of the format doesn't get scattered all over your code.* This way, changes become trivial.

Comment: @this.lau_ after some thought I think the separator representation is the best... Could you please update your answer so that I can accept it with the most relevant info? And thanks maaartinus for the suggestion, I will implement a class to take care of it.